# Help for structuring classes

Tags: unity, c#, software-engineering

I am creating a platformer game with some card base fighting. I was thinking  about how should I structure my classes? There are 2 types of cards i.e. Continuous effect and 1 time effect. Also, they can be divide into 3 other categories i.e. Environment cards, enemy cards and player cards. Please help me to get started with structuring it.

For more details, I want structure to be reusable as well as organized. Enemies and player both can interact with these cards and at some points.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think we have enough information about your game here to give you well-tailored architectural advice. Fortunately, in Unity, you can often be pretty loose with your structure. Making each card an unrelated Monobehaviour, or having them implement a very minimal base class or interface's "ActivateCard()" method will likely get you what you need, with lots of flexibility to change things up as you prototype with different kinds of cards and rules.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I also have to randomly generate cards, so, for holding all the cards which data structure will be good list or dictionary?

Comment: Depends what you want to do. A list is good if you want to access entries by index, like drawing the top card off a deck (or a random card from the middle). A dictionary is good if you want to look up cards by some associated label, like finding a card by name.